# Sharepoint tasks being carried over via template libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-tasks-list

I'm working on a SharePoint library which is derived from a template. The original Sharepoint library had a number of Sharepoint workflows applied onto it, and had columns which showed up as 'Completed' based on if that workflow was achieved or not.

The new Sharepoint library which was derived from the template is working correctly, apart from one thing; it seems that the SharePoint workflows are carried over from the original library to the new one that is created from the template. How do I remove them? And why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the workflow, go library settings>Workflow settings>Remove, Block, or Restore a Workflow> and check all the workflows you do not need to remove. Then delete the columns you do not need.

It seems you save a library with workflow as template and use that template to create new library. Per my test the template will contain the workflows associated with the list/library and corresponding columns.